# Finding the Sum of a Jagged Array

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

*Homework

I'm trying to add the values in an array. With the sum method I wrote below, the program only works for arrays that are not jagged. If I test a jagged array, I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. What's the next step I should take to try and make this method work if the array is jagged?

```
int sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            sum += array[j][i];
        } 
    }
return sum;
}
```

Comment: you test `array[i].length`, yet you access `array[j]`

Answer (score 2):

Your method is close, but it has a small bug - this

```
sum += array[j][i];
```

should be

```
sum += array[i][j];
```

Note that your inner loop is iterating over `array[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the indices:

```
sum += array[i][j];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing indexes. You are first looping through rows (`i`) , then through columns (`j`), but when you access to the array elements, you are using `j` for the rows and `i` for the columns.

It should be:

```
sum += array[i][j];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`sum += array[j][i];`

to

`sum += array[i][j];`